# Character Set Mismatch Error in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have following query with me that I am trying to run:

```
SELECT Script from (

SELECT 9 as ColOrder, ' INSERT INTO PROJ VALUES(' || ID || ',''' || Name || ''', ''' || Version || ''', ''ABCD'', sysdate , ''ABCD'', sysdate);' as Script FROM PROJ where Name like '%[Param.1]%'

union

SELECT 11 as ColOrder,' INSERT INTO PROJMOD VALUES(' || ID || ', ' || ProjID || ', ' || ModID || ', ' || ObjID || ', ''ABCD'', sysdate, ''ABCD'', sysdate);' as Script FROM PROJMOD where ProjID in ( select ID from PROJ where Name like '%[Param.1]%')

) x

Order by ColOrder
```

But it gives me `ORA-12704: character set mismatch error.`

When I run both the select statement individually, it gives me proper output but when I am doing union of both select, it gives tme character set mismatch error.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: As colorder isn't mergable try union all instead of union. Do any of the columns have nvarchar or nchar data types?

Comment: Yes, 'ABCD' column is of NVARCHAR2. I tried using UNION ALL but it gives me same error.

Comment: it wont be the literal ABCD but a column (id projid or name etc) see my answer for details.

Answer (score 15):

as you've confirmed some things are NVARchar'd ..cast the nvarchar to char eg

```
SQL> create table tab(a nvarchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tab values ('a');

1 row created.

SQL> select 1, 'hi' from dual
  2  union all
  3  select 2, a from tab;
select 1, 'hi' from dual
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

fails as "A" is NVARCHAR. so to_char it:

```
SQL> select 1, 'hi' from dual
  2  union all
  3  select 2, to_char(a) from tab;

         1 'HI'
---------- ----
         1 hi
         2 a
```

or cast the string literal 'hi' to a Nvarchar

```
   SQL> select 1, n'hi' from dual
      2  union all
      3  select 2, a from tab;

             1 N'
    ---------- --
             1 hi
             2 a
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Script from (

SELECT 9 as ColOrder, ' INSERT INTO PROJ VALUES(' || to_char(ID) || ',''' || to_char(Name) || ''', ''' || to_char(Version) || ''', ''ABCD'', sysdate , ''ABCD'', sysdate);' as Script FROM PROJ where Name like '%[Param.1]%'

union

SELECT 11 as ColOrder,' INSERT INTO PROJMOD VALUES(' || to_char(ID) || ', ' || to_char(ProjID) || ', ' || to_char(ModID) || ', ' || to_char(ObjID) || ', ''ABCD'', sysdate, ''ABCD'', sysdate);' as Script FROM PROJMOD where ProjID in ( select ID from PROJ where Name like '%[Param.1]%')

) x

Order by ColOrder
```

I just added TO_CHAR functions, and that will work. apparently you have fields with character data types that cannot be implicitly cast by Oracle, so you just need to cast it explicitly yourself, however be careful to avoid any character loss due to cast.

Comment: you dont need and shouldn't use union in this case. use "union all"

Answer (score 0):

If you take this error,  you should look at two conditions.

1. All column name or alias must be same for all tables
2. All column must be same type TableA(col NVARCHAR2), TableB(col
   NVARCHAR2)