# Error: ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
SELECT
     null AS m_inout_id,
     'OPEN' AS documentno         
FROM
     adempiere.transaction_view trv    
UNION ALL
SELECT
     trv.m_inout_id AS m_inout_id,
     trv.documentno AS documentno
FROM
     adempiere.transaction_view trv
```

The problem is with documentno. The datatype of documentno is NVARCHAR2(20).

Comment: If you think this will be useful to someone in the future - and I think it might - then you should make that an answer. Although it's almost a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15967201/266304) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13354436/266304). You might also want to consider casting `null` to the same data type as `trv.m_inout_id`; or reversing the order of the queries.

Comment: I'm seeking a query working both in oracle and postgres.

Comment: Does PostgreSQL understand the `n'OPEN'` syntax?

Comment: It is working fine in postgres