# How can I resolve datatype error between Oracle and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have two databases, let's say DB `A` and DB `T`, also I have a db-link between them. DB T is on Oracle and DB A is on SQL Server.

I have a query that combines data from both A and T:

```
SELECT flight_date,
       flight,
       destination
FROM flights@T
UNION
SELECT flight_date,
       flight,
       destination
FROM flights@A
```

But I keep getting error:

> ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

It's pointing to 2nd line.

`Flights` in database `T` have `VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)` datatype, while `FLIGHT` in database `A` has `smallint` datatype.

Have you faced this issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: _"How can I solve it?"_ - with a `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

Comment: I have tried both CAST and CONVERT, but still the same error

Comment: Show us how you used `CAST/CONVERT` in your SQL.

Comment: I would convert the INT to varchar.   It would be safer than trusting the conversion of string to an int

Comment: CAST(FLIGHT AS VARCHAR(10))  
But now I get the error ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Comment: Apparently you need `TO_CHAR` instead of `CAST`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354436/character-set-mismatch-error-in-oracle